# Causes for random break points unknown

Tags: vba, excel, random

This has been a long and unresolved problem with Excel VBA code that runs a repeated loop via the `Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(x,x,x)`. Users will find that their code is running fine for a few days and may, or may not, mysteriously stop.

I'm facing such a situation and hoping to resolve it. I've read over 30 forum answers, some written by experienced developers, and came to this understanding. My conclusion and question follow.

The conclusion is that Excel **randomly** goes into a `break mode` but no one knows the **reason** why this occurs, more so, why it randomly occurs.

Shall we then conclude that in fact this randomly occurs? And that Excel VBA isn't as robust as other languages.

Some notes:

1. I know this can be resolved by pressing `Ctrl+Break` twice. It doesn't explain why we have to do it in the first place.
2. I realize that this error is code independent. It'll occur with both simple and involved programs.
3. After trying multiple ways to simulate this error, and I mean a lot - long and multiple ADODB SQL connections and queries, cell editing while macro is running, using multiple and 1 second `Application.OnTime` recursive calling, I can't replicate the error. It is truly random.
4. I'm running only one workbook and one Excel instance.
5. Some say, for each break point we did in the debugging, that break point remains in memory. And then when we run a macro in the future, a write to that part of memory triggers this random break. This **is** a plausible explanation and does conclude that this error is random. No way can we inspect memory in VBA.

I need something to go by, even if it isn't to solve this problem, to act as proof for my boss.

Comment: This is happening for users that HAVE NOT previously pressed `Ctrl+Break` either during the current session or on that workbook?

Comment: I cannot ascertain whether I have experienced this error when I HAVE pressed Ctrl+Break during the current session or on that workbook. 

1. If the answer is yes, that is pressed Ctrl+Break before running code, it is still a random error.
2. If the answer is no, user doesn't know whether Ctrl+Break was pressed or not before running of code, it is still a random error.

I'm questioning its randomness and the cause of it.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the bug! I've not read this answer to this problem before so it is pivotal that the Excel community receives this.

Excel fails to call its sub routines in the `Application OnTime` queue whenever this happens. You have started to edit a cell, stayed in edit mode, and then switched away from Excel either by minimizing the window or by clicking onto another window.

All the sub routines in the `Application OnTime` queue will wait until the cell is finished editing. So once you switch back to Excel, the cell switches edit mode off, and then all the sub routines will run.

I'm actually quite impressed I solved this myself.